# Tracking campaign with allowanchor

Tags: google-analytics

If I add the `{'allowAnchor':true}` to my Universal analytic code in such a way:

```
 ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX', {'allowAnchor':true}, 'auto')
```

Will I be able to track all my campaigns on Analytic for all my blog posts with `#` instead of `?` ??? Or do I also need to add some more piece of code to my pages?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the documentation true is actually the default value:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#allowAnchor)

> By default, analytics.js will search for custom campaign parameters
>   such as utm_source, utm_medium, etc. in both the query string and
>   anchor of the current page's URL. Setting this field to false will
>   result in ignoring any custom campaign parameters that appear in the
>   anchor.
>
> Field Name  allowAnchor
>   Value Type  boolean
>   Default Value true

So not only do you not need extra code, you don't even need to set it to true (I have to admit I'm just quoting the docs here, this used to be different in older versions of GA and I wasn't aware until now that this has changed).

Comment: Thank you Eike, so if leave it as it is, I can use # in all my links with campaign parameters? I'll leave true just in case as we never know.

Comment: Yes. You can easily check in the realtime view if this works (realtime displays source/medium information).